Excel Ribbon comboBox: set page scale value (for mac)
One difference between Excel for Windows and Excel for Mac is the Page Setup control “Scale”. Excel for Windows has this as a built-in control, you can simply add it to your ribbon by using
<control idMso="PageScaleToFitScale" />
This idMso is not available in Excel for Mac:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/office-mac/idmsoexcelmac
The following code is a little workaround: you can set 3 scale values (or more).
Question: is there a way to feed the code with the whole scale range from 10 to 400 other than building a "Case" for every value?
Thanks!
' -- XML

<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="LoadRibbon">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab id="Tabv3.1" label="TOOLS" insertAfterMso="TabHome">                            
                <group id="GroupDemo2" 
                label="Page Scale"
                imageMso="AddInManager">
                    <comboBox id="ComboBox001"
                    label="comboBox001"
                    getText="ComboBox001_GetText"
                    onChange="ComboBox001_OnChange">
                        <item id="Scale_100"
                        label="100%"/>
                        <item id="Scale_77"
                        label="77%"/>
                        <item id="Scale_68"
                        label="68%"/>
                    </comboBox>
                </group> 
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>


' -- Standard Module

Option Explicit
Public RibUI As IRibbonUI

Sub LoadRibbon(Ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set RibUI = Ribbon
    RibUI.InvalidateControl "ComboBox001"
End Sub

'Callback for ComboBox001 onChange
Sub ComboBox001_OnChange(control As IRibbonControl, id As String)
    Dim iSize As Long
    Select Case id
        Case "100%"
             iSize = 100
        Case "77%"
            iSize = 77
        Case "68%"
            iSize = 68
    End Select
    If iSize > 0 Then _
        ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Zoom = iSize
End Sub

'Callback for ComboBox001 getText
Sub ComboBox001_getText(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    returnedVal = GetPageScale
End Sub

Function GetPageScale() As String
        Select Case ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Zoom
        Case 100
            GetPageScale = "100%"
        Case 77
            GetPageScale = "77%"
        Case 68
            GetPageScale = "68%"
        End Select
End Function


' -- ThisWorkbook

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    RibUI.InvalidateControl "ComboBox001"
End Sub


If you want a range from 10 to 400 then maybe use a textbox instead of a combo?  Or just convert by adding/subtracting the %  Eg GetPageScale = ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Zoom & "%"   or iSize = CLng(Replace(id, "%", ""))
